# Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I have checked other questions with the same problem, but they don't work for mine.

I am getting the error: `Cannot set property '0' of undefined` with my JavaScript; I am using Google Chrome.

```
var thisInstance = new Grid(100,100);
thisInstance.initGrid();

function Grid(maxX, maxY) {
    this.grid     = new Array();
    this.gridMaxX = maxX;
    this.gridMaxY = maxY;

    this.initGrid = function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.gridMaxX; i++) {
            this.grid[i] = new Array();
        }
    }
}
```

And I get the error when I call: 
`thisInstance[1][0] = 1;`

Please ask if you need more information!

Comment: why did you do it like, `thisInstance[1][0] = 1;`. thisInstance is a Grid object. thisInstance[1] does not refer to anything here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is fired because you are trying to access `[0]` on an undefined object.

Replace

```
thisInstance[1][0] = 1;
```

by

```
thisInstance.grid[1][0] = 1;
```

`thisInstance` is just an instance of `Grid`, not an array.

Comment: Er.. switch the [0] and [1] around.. ya got it backwards :)

Comment: Not to completely hijack your answer (but maybe get you an extra point or two) - new Array(); should be replaced by []. It's a quite a bit slower than the [] version (http://jsperf.com/array-literal-vs-new-array).

Answer (score -1):

In this part of the code:

```
this.initGrid = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.gridMaxX; i++) {
        this.grid[i] = new Array();
    }
}
```

`this.initGrid` and `this.grid` do not refer to the same object 'this'.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I really think they do. I mean, technically they don't have to, in that `this.initGrid` is referring to the object being constructed, and `this.grid` is referring to the object that the `initGrid` method is being called on, but the OP's code, and in expected/typical usage, those two will be the same object.

Comment: In "this" case (har har), both references of "this" do indeed refer to the same object. The function Grid is used as a constructor, so within the constructor, "this" refers to the object being initialized. The function initGrid becomes a member of that object as well. Within a function that is a member of another object, "this" refers to the containing object.